# url path is coming wrongly in php

Tags: php, web-services, url

I am having a web service which returns some images url, the service is working fine but the issue is that the url is not coming correctly.

My code is as given below

```
$obj->book_title = "test.jpg";
$url = "http://www.example.com/uploads/books/thumb/".$obj->book_title;
```

the above code outputs as

```
http:\/\/www.example.com\/uploads\/books\/thumb\/test.jpg
```

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

Comment: looks as though it's been escaped before it's being returned, just unescape it where ever you're using it?

Comment: many ways.. first that pops to mind is `stripslashes`

Comment: You are just defining variables in the code you have shown. How are you outputting it exactly?

Comment: the above code is not the problem. php doesn't know what a url is, and will NOT mangle your variable just because it has a url. you're doing something else later on to cause this escaping to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code listed should not do that, there is something else in your code that makes it output like that... you could try this

```
$obj->book_title = "test.jpg";
$url = "http://www.example.com/uploads/books/thumb/".$obj->book_title;
$url = str_replace("\\", "", $url);
echo $url;
```

Comment: still its not resloved

Comment: how do you output the $url ?